# How to convert my output to Matrices in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I am newbie to javascript.I pretty confused that how to convert my output to matix formation like this..

From this output to

Output

```
MachineId:M1 Jobs done By this Machine:(j5 = 8),(j4 = 7),(j3 = 1) Time consumed to finish all jobs:16
MachineId:M2 Jobs done By this Machine:(j2 = 9),(j6 = 5),(j1 = 4) Time consumed to finish all jobs:18
MachineId:M3 Jobs done By this Machine:(j7 = 22) Time consumed to finish all jobs:22
MachineId:M4 Jobs done By this Machine:(j8 = 32) Time consumed to finish all jobs:32
```

This output should be printed

```
  [8,7,1][16],
    [9,5,4][18],
    [22,0,0][22],
    [32,0,0][32]
```

This is my Actual code produce the first mentioned output

```
 // real algorithm
    //total Jobs
    var _ = require('underscore');
    var njobs = [{
        jobname: "j1",
        time: 4
    }, {
        jobname: "j2",
        time: 9
    }, {
        jobname: "j3",
        time: 1
    }, {
        jobname: "j4",
        time: 7
    }, {
        jobname: "j5",
        time: 8
    }, {
        jobname: "j6",
        time: 5
    }, {
        jobname: "j7",
        time: 22
    },
        {
            jobname: "j8",
            time: 32
        }

    ];

    //sort this data with time
    var sorted = njobs.sort((a, b) => b.time - a.time);

    console.log('Jobs Inserted ====================>')

    sorted.map(function (data) {
        console.log('JobId:'+data.jobname+' Time to finish this Job :'+data.time)
    });

    //List all the machines
    var machines = [
        {
            id:1,
            value:0,
            jobs:[],
            name:'M1'
        },
        {
            id:2,
            value:0,
            jobs:[],
            name:'M2'
        },
        {
            id:3,
            value:0,
            jobs:[],
            name:'M3'
        },
        {
            id:3,
            value:0,
            jobs:[],
            name:'M4'
        }
    ];
    console.log('Machines Available :'+ machines.length);
    //Loop it and assign it
    sorted.forEach(job => {
        var minMachine = machines
            .slice(1)
            .reduce((res, cur) =>
                res.value < cur.value ? res : cur, machines[0]);

        minMachine.jobs.push(job);
        minMachine.value += job.time;
    });


    //Prints the value

    console.log('Output =====================================>');



    machines.map(function (data) {
        console.log('MachineId:'+data.name+' Jobs done By this Machine:'+data.jobs.map(data => '('+data.jobname+' = '+data.time+')')+' Time consumed to finish all jobs:'+data.value)
    });



    var high = Math.max.apply(Math,machines.map(function (o) {
        return o.value;
    }));
    console.log('______________________________________________')
    console.log('Highest Time consuming Machine =========>');
    var result = _.findWhere(machines,{value:high});
    console.log(result.name+' is the highest running Machine  '+result.value);

    // machines.map(function (){...}).reduce(function (total, curr) { return total + curr; });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your JavaScript.

```
// Build the multidimensional array.
var arr = [];
var maxJobsPerMachine = 0;
machines.map(function (data) {
    var marr = [];
    marr.push(data.jobs.map(data => data.time));
    maxJobsPerMachine=Math.max(maxJobsPerMachine, marr[0].length);
    marr.push([data.value])
    arr.push(marr);
});
arr.forEach(e => { while (e[0].length < maxJobsPerMachine) e[0].push(0); });

// Print it.
arr.forEach(e => { 
    var line = ""; 
    e.forEach(f => line += "[" + f.join(",") + "]");
    console.log(line);
});
```

Here is the output:

```
[8,7,1][16]
[9,5,4][18]
[22,0,0][22]
[32,0,0][32]
```

Comment: Thanx Bro..You are great